# I am getting an error in npm start command, what should I do?

Tags: node.js

Please help with this

I have created react app with command create-react-app my-app
and then ran npm start and thus got the error , tried multiple times but still same error. Please help with this
[Npm error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoSDR.png)

[full error message on running npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7xwN.png)
[package.json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNT3J.png)

Comment: Can you post what your package.json looks like. Also, double check that you've changed to the my-app directory before running `npm start`.

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
}

Comment: That doesn't look correct. I don't think the `create-react-app` command finished because the scripts section and most of the dependencies are missing. I'd try running it again `npx create-react-app my-app `

Comment: {
  "name": "my-app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
} again same issue sir

Comment: A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your `package.json` file.

You will find something like this :

```
`"name": "app name",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@devloco/react-scripts-wptheme": "3.3.1-wp.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
}`
```

The `scripts` part is the one where you can add custom commands to type it in the terminal, you should check if there is a `start` command there, if there isn't you can use the example above.

Comment: it look like this {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
}

Comment: go to the same level of dependencies and add this : "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
}

Comment: this is displayed in command promt npm ERR! code EJSONPARSEnpm ERR! file C:\Users\Saood Ahmad\my-app\package.jsonnpm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse jsonnpm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 173 while parsing '{npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "my-app",npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": "0.1.'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saood Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-20T21_21_28_062Z-debug.log

Comment: how did you create the react application ?

Comment: npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: can you take a screen for your package.json file and put it in the question please ?

Comment: placed screenshot sir!